# Node JS spawn input text when prompted

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I'm using the Node JS Child Process to run a command, I need to somehow automatically enter some text when prompted and press enter automatically from within my `stdout`, not sure how to do that...

```js
var child = spawn('COMMAND-TO-RUN', {
  shell: true
});

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  // when prompted in the terminal, need to input something automatically from here...
  console.log(data)
  console.log("STDOUT:", data.toString());
});
```

**UPDATE**

I've already tried to use `child.stdin.write` and this didn't work in the context of my problem where the terminal is prompting for a SSH password since I'm trying to automate inputting a password into the terminal through the JS, not sure why this doesn't work.

Comment: `child.stdin.write(stuff to write)`

Comment: @shamsup I've already tried this, it doesn't write anything when I'm prompted in the terminal. For context (on a mac terminal) it's trying to connect to a server through SSH and prompts me for the password to that sever after some time. `stdin.write` appears not to write anything.

Comment: If you append a `'\n'` to the input does it work? The line feed signifies the submission of the prompt.

Comment: Appears not to work, tried adding a `setTimeout` as well

Comment: It seems that Node JS is unable to input text into a `ssh root@IP` command that was ran in a terminal, which is annoying.

Comment: It must be some other reason then as `child.stdin.write('...\n')` does work as a way to write on stdin.

Comment: @manishg I just don't think it's possible since the Node JS script exists when the ssh comes up and is prompted

Comment: There is probably not a generic way to do that. `ssh` doesn't read the password from standard input, otherwise something like `echo password | ssh host` would work. Instead standard input gets passed to the command on the remote side. This may or may not help: https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the child's stdin and stderr to the parent process. For example:

```
var child = spawn('ps', {
    shell: true
});

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    // when prompted in the terminal, need to input something automatically from here...
    process.stdout.write('Something I want to print\n\n');
    console.log(data)
    console.log("STDOUT:", data.toString());
});
```

[image]

Comment: @ryan-holton, here is the screenshot of the output.